# How to index into the string result of a dictionary item reference?

Tags: python

What is the best syntax to reference the characters in a reference to dictionary item? How do I make it indexable?

```
>>> myd = {'abc':'123','def':'456','ghi':'789'}
>>> myd
{'def': '456', 'ghi': '789', 'abc': '123'}
>>> type(myd)
<class 'dict'>
>>> s=myd['def']
>>> s
'456'
>>> type(s)
<class 'str'>
>>> s[0]
'4'
>>> s[2]
'6'
>>> myd['def'].[0]
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `myd['def']` *produces* a string. As you showed in your first example, you do not need a `.` to index *into* a string

Comment: `What is the best syntax to ...` - one that works and is easy to understand when read.

Comment: I think your question is misleading. First you try to create syntactically valid code, then you can think about "best syntax". Also: What IDE do you use? It could detect these simple errors.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `.` and it will work.

You have not actually sliced your string.  Once you get the value `myd['def']` it returns a string.  You then need to use `[]` to slice it.  `[0]` in this case however adding a `.` is just a syntax error in Python.

[This link describes slicing strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

Answer (score 1):

`myd['def']` returns you the string `'456'`. You can access a specific index of an array using the same bracket notation that most languages support. Hence, `myd['def'][0]` will return the string literal `'4'`